# send mail after three hours of a database entry

Tags: php, email, cron

I have a specific scenario where i have to send email from my php application. Please     consider the following situation:

If an email is submitted to database at say 10 AM, i want to send an welcome email at 1 PM automatically, i can use cron jobs if i have to do it at a particular interval of time, but it this case there is no set time but i have to run my mail script after every three hours whenever a email is inserted into database.

Please suggest, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set your cron job to run every minute and write your script in that to check emails which are register before 3 hours and send mail to matching emails.
Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

How about running your cron every hour and then detect when the initial email was sent? If the interval is 3 hours, then you send a welcome email. But your cron will "wake up" every hour to see if there are any welcome messages needing to be sent.